# Por que "irmão" não tem acento? Se é uma oxítona terminada em "o"

Tags: português-brasileiro

Uma dúvida:

Se "irmão" é uma oxítona e as oxítonas terminadas em "o" são acentuadas, por que não há acento em "irmão"?
Lembrando: "~" não é acento.

Answer (score 5):

Se a palavra fosse, digamos, "irmãô" ou "irmãó", sua pronúncia seria marcadamente diferente da usual.
Em palavras oxítonas terminadas em "ão", o til já serve para marcar a tonicidade (cf. [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/til-mais-uma-vez/8544) ou [Norma Culta](https://www.normaculta.com.br/palavras-com-ao/)) e [não são](https://mundoeducacao.uol.com.br/gramatica/palavras-oxitonas.htm) acentuadas.

Com relação à regra, o "ão" em "irmão" [é](https://www.normaculta.com.br/palavras-com-ao/) um ditongo nasal decrescente, ou seja, o "o" não é tônico e pode ser considerado uma semivogal, enquanto a regra prescreve a acentuação do "o" final apenas quando vogal tônica (grifo meu):

[Dicio dúvidas](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/principais-duvidas-na-acentuacao-grafica/):

> São acentuadas graficamente as palavras oxítonas terminadas nas **vogais tônicas** -a, -e, -o, nos ditongos nasais -em ou -ens e nos ditongos abertos -ói, -éu, -éi.

[Norma Culta](https://www.normaculta.com.br/palavras-oxitonas/):

> Apenas são acentuadas graficamente as palavras oxítonas terminadas nas **vogais tônicas** -á, -ás,- é, -és, -ó, -ós, nos ditongos abertos -ói, -éu, -éi e nos ditongos nasais -ém, -éns.

E também [aqui](https://gramaticaonline.com.br/gramatica/da-acentuacao-grafica-das-palavras-oxitonas/), [aqui](https://www.educamaisbrasil.com.br/enem/lingua-portuguesa/palavras-oxitonas), [aqui (pg. 27](https://repositorio.ufmg.br/browse?type=author&value=Amarildo+Viana+Marra); [e-print](http://www.poslin.letras.ufmg.br/defesas/1464M.pdf)), entre outros.